# Rewrite CPT permalinks to subdomains

Tags: url-rewriting

Can I use wp_rewrite or other to change CPT permalinks to subdomains.

From:

> [example.com/cpt/*]

To:

> [*.example.com]

Comment: it is not possible

Comment: Or just change it without mapping or rewrite?